# how do I update files on an cached iPhone web app with cache.manifest

Tags: iphone, caching, web-applications

I have an iPhone web app which uses a cache.manifest file to successfully cache files. The problem starts when I want to update the app while it uses the old files because of the cache.

How do I make the cache.manifest file to update the new files correctly?
Can I define a version or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update text within the manifest itself - e.g. a version number within a comment.

See:
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#offline

Also see question 1715568